# Ms project - removal of base calendar nonworking time not feeding through to resource calendars

Tags: ms-project-2016

I created recurring nonworking time on a base calendar. It correctly worked through onto the relevent resource calendars.
I added some nonworking time to individual resource calendars and all is still as expected.
However, when I go back to base calendar and delete the recurring non working time, the resource calendars still have that base non working time in there and I cannot schedule tasks for those resources at that time (was every Friday as non working in the base calendar).
When I look are resource usage, those days are set as nonworking on graphic view. The time is not explicitly shown as nonworking in either base exemptions or resource exemptions tho.

Only way I have found to solve this is add each Friday explicitly as working time for each resource calendar. Even adding as explicitly working time of base calendar does not work.

I assume the resource calendars take copies of their base calendars rather than inherit from them?
What are the rules re deletions from base calendars? Can't find any.

Thanks in advance.